# How to scale the font size of a font that is from a Skin?

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

I downloaded this skin to use for a game that I am working on: 
https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-skins/tree/master/plain-james

When I run my app on a Amazon Fire Tablet that has a lower pixel density, the font shows up normally. However, when I run the app on an emulator of a phone that has a higher pixel density (Nexus 5X), the font (and also the button, but the button size scales with the font) shows up super small:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLW8a.png)

Is there a way that I can scale the font so that it fits a higher pixel density?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using viewport ?

Comment: Yeah. I am using the ScreenViewport to create a stage that the table containing the font text is an actor of.

Comment: show your code ?

Comment: `stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport(), game.batch);`

Comment: use `ExtendViewport` instead of `ScreenViewport`